# Vault's LDAP authentication's (Authentication failed: ldap operation failed: failed to bind as user)

Tags: ldap, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to use the ldap authentication util for the Vault's infrastructure.

Running :

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://my.ldap.ip.addr \
-x -b "DC=<mydomain>,DC=<mydomain>" \
-D "CN=Username,OU=Users,OU=fulldomain,DC=domain,DC=domain -W
```

I am successfully authenticated and returns the ldap tree.

Now  Vault's configuration has the following parameters :

```
vault write auth/ldap/config \
url="ldap://ldapurl" \
insecure_tls="true" \
userdn=" ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=mydomain" \
case_sensitive_names="true" \
binddn="*Same dn as in the ldpasearch command*" \
groupdn="OU= Groups,OU=mydomain,DC=mydomain" \
groupattr="cn"
```

When I try to log with ldap via the Vault's UI there is the following error:

> Authentication failed: ldap operation failed: failed to bind as user

The ldap queries are copied from the response of the ldap search so I believe I am not mistyping the queries.

I overwrote several times the vault's path auth/ldap/config with `'vault auth disable/enable ldap'`
(It seemed that the config was not updating new config parameters so I reset and wrote them again, could not find any other solution)

What could be the origin of the error and how I can debug this error?

Highly appreciated any comments/help.

Kudos

Answer (score 0):

Does your AD (I presume you query Active Directory via LDAP) allow anonymous LDAP access? I do not see a bindpass provided in the Vault config, you will need to provide it if your AD does not allow anonymous access.